# Implementation of a reduce procedure in racket with three arguments: function, base and a list

Tags: racket

My task is to implement a **reduce** procedure that takes a function that adds, or multiplies, or divides, each number in a list. I am stuck with the argument base. I have been able to check through the list of numbers and apply the function passed as argument. However, in the recursive call, I don't know how to handle the base number. I don't want the recursion to take into account the argument base in every call (base could be any number).

Here is what I have been able to do:

```
(define (reduce f base lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) base)
        (else (f (f base (first lst)) (reduce f base (rest lst))))))
```

When base is 0 it passes the test for addition:

```
> (test (reduce + 0 '(1 2 3)) 6)
good (reduce + 0 '(1 2 3)) at line 3
  expected: 6
  given: 6
```

However, when base is 1, the test fails because base is added in the recursion call every time:

```
> (test (reduce + 1 '(1 2 3)) 7)
bad (reduce + 1 '(1 2 3)) at line 13
  expected: 7
  given: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are arguments in `lst` to process, then you want to combine the first argument with the result of processing the rest of `lst`. But, with `(f (f base (first lst)) (reduce f base (rest lst)))` the posted code is combining the result of `(f base (first lst))` with the result of processing the rest of `lst`. Since the test is using `+`, this means that at every step `base` is added to the next item of `lst`, and that sum is combined with the remainder of the computation.

Instead, just use `f` to combine the next element of `lst` with the result of reducing the rest of `lst`:

```
(define (reduce f base lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) base)
        (else (f (first lst) (reduce f base (rest lst))))))
```

```
scratch.rkt> (reduce + 1 '(1 2 3))
7
```